# Animating a SVG gradient

Tags: animation, svg, gradient

I'd like to generate an SVG gradient that varies over time.

In this example code, I'd like to generate an ellipse whose gradient is red with a yellow stripe that travels from west to east over time (creating a shimmer effect):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" >
        <animate 
          attributeName="offset" 
          from="0%"
          to="100%"
          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </stop>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
</svg>
```

This doesn't work yet, but I'm not sure whether it's because I'm doing it wrong, or it's not an effect I can achieve with SVG gradients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need a time period for the animation. Add `dur="5s"` for instance as an attribute of the `animate` element.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" >
        <animate 
          attributeName="offset" 
          from="0%"
          to="100%"
          dur="5s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </stop>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: @Denis I guess you'll need to raise a Chrome bug on [its bugtracker](https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/)

Comment: Don't use "%'s" for your stops and animate values - use decimals - then it all works.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yFthP/) that works on Firefox and Chrome:

The values attribute that is provided in the spec [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#ValueAttributes) is used in this example.

```
<linearGradient id="myG">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#f15361">
</stop>
<stop offset=".25" stop-color="#fbaf4a">
<animate attributeName="offset" dur="5s" values="0;1;0"
    repeatCount="indefinite" />
</stop>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#f15361"/>
```